# Macro runs fine on Windows but does not on Mac

Tags: macos, vba, ms-office, ms-word, office-2016

I have a Word document which is used for form filling purpose. The users are filling what is asked and some macros runs depending on what they chose or where they click. This works fine. Or at least, on my Windows operating system.

I myself, as well as most of my users, use Microsoft Office and everything I made works here.

That being said, several users are beginning to use Apple product such as MacBooks.

The thing is, I thought that them using Office 2016 on OS X won't cause any problem. Surprisingly enough for me, it apparently does not work properly. Now after some research, I found out that ActiveX controls (which my document contains) does not work in Office 2016. Therefore, my ComboBox and some other TextBox does not work for them.

**Is there a way to make fix it or do I need to change every ActiveX control and make them Legacy options ? Is there an easier way than changing all I've yet done ?**

**EDIT 1 :** Is there a way to use ComboBoxes and Texboxes without ActiveX controls (e.i. by using some sort of legacy control) ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try making a simple wix-website, which does the same thing. Even tough you have to retype everything. Another possibility is to convert ur word into libreoffice-write.

Comment: I thought about making a simple WPF app or a simple ASP.NET website a while back when I was assigned this project but never got the go to make it happen. That being said, I thought it would work for MAC too. Thought that Microsoft would do the same product for both OS but turns out it's not the case. I'll add your solution (making a website out of it) to my list and see what happens. Thanks for your proposition.